# Sort a table that appears when a submit button after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table, tablesorter

I am having some trouble in using tablesorter jquery plugin.
The thing is that I have a view that when a submit button is clicked, depending on the search of the form, a table with information from the database is loaded. This table is only displayed when the Search button is clicked and not always display the same information. I have tried to use tablesorter jquery plugin but it doesn't seem to work. I am calling:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<head>
<script>
function sort_my_table(){
$('my_table').tablesorter();
}
</script>
</head>
```

and then the table below.

When I press this button the table shows up at the bottom of the page, the button is submitting a form where you enter the information that you want and then there is a search using this info and the table displays the result of the search:

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="search" name="send">
```

My table looks like this:

```
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th  style="text-align:center">Code</th>
                    <th  style="text-align:center">Name</th>
                    <th  style="text-align:center">Description</th>
                </tr>    
            </thead>

            <?php foreach ($elements as $element) { ?>
            <tbody> 
                <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $element->fabr?></td>
                        <?php if (count($element->place) > 0) { ?>
                                <td>
                                <?php foreach ($element->place as $pl) { ?>
                                    <?php echo $pl['name'] ?><br>
                                <?php } ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <?php foreach ($element->place as $pl) { ?>
                                    <?php echo $pl['number'] ?><br>
                                <?php } ?>
                                </td>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <?php } ?>                           
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody> 
    </table>
```

I really don't know how to use it or how to make it work.

Comment: Make sure `my_table` is a "proper" css selector... it should use a class name (period; `.my_table`) or id (hash; `#my_table`) to target the table.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the tablesorter to sort your table when the document is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $('my_table').tablesorter();
    } 
);
```

Click on the headers and you'll see that your table is now sortable.
(This will only work if the table itself isn't manipulated or overwritten directly)

http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

Comment: I tried adding this but it doesn't work. The thing is that when the document is loaded the table is not yet in the page. It only shows up if I click the search button.

Comment: How do you accomplish the hiding and displaying? Via jquery ".hide()" and ".show()" ? Can you provide us more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to move the script that is fired on click.

If you want it to load before the click you can use this:

https://jsfiddle.net/MaXiNoM/4ggnL81h/

```
$(function(){
  $("#myTable").tablesorter();
});
```

if you want the table to be blank then pass it null params, this will let you load a blank table. It sounds a call that is fired from an onclick, which is also when your table is rendered and populated. You could try taking the call directly from there and putting that into your onload.